# M-estimator as a quantile estimator

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation, quantile, robust-statistics

According to the answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/497785/310702,
$\alpha$-quantile sample estimator can be considered as M-estimator with
$\rho(y_i,\theta)=\alpha(y_i-\theta)_+ + (1-\alpha)(\theta-y_i)_+$.

From the definition of M-estimator I understand that the M-estimator is of the form
$$
\theta^* = \mathrm{argmin}_\theta \sum_{i=1}^n \rho(y_i, \theta)
$$
But it's not clear to me why $\rho(y_i, \theta)$ given above is a quantile estimator. Specifically, I'm confuesed by + sign after parentheses.

Comment: I would presume $(y_i-\theta)_+ = \max(0, y_i-\theta)$, i.e. the value in brackets if positive or $0$ otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Henry notes, the $+$ sign means the positive part, $x_+ = \max(0, x)$. Hence the loss $\rho$ has derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\theta} = \alpha 1(y > \theta) - (1 - \alpha) 1(y \le \theta),$$

and the expected loss $\mathbb E\rho$ has derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial\mathbb E\rho}{\partial\theta} = \alpha \mathbb P(y > \theta) - (1 - \alpha) \mathbb P(y \le \theta),$$

which is zeroed when $\theta$ is the $\alpha$-quantile of the $Y_i$.